# How to change color of registered widget areas in admin?

Tags: widgets, admin

Right now they are all gray.

How to change the color?

I mean, how to add a class or id to the registered widget area that are shown in the admin area?

This is how you register the admin areas in my functions.php right now:

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
```

How can I add some attribute to add class in the admin, so I can style it later via CSS?

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to style the sidebar in the backend, you do not need to do anything else. when you use the code you posted, the html created by WordPress for the sidebar contain a div with the id attribute equal to the id of the sidebar.

Consider this code:

```
function custom_colored_sidebar() {

  register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Test Sidebar',
    'id' => 'sidebar-test',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</aside>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

  add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'widget_style');

}

function widget_style( $page ) {
  if ( $page == 'widgets.php' ) {
    echo '<style>div#sidebar-test { background-color:#f00; }</style>';
  }
}

add_action('init', 'custom_colored_sidebar');
```

As you can see I registered a sidebar with the id `'sidebar-test'` and then I used `'admin_enqueue_scripts'` to put some style on a div withe the id `'sidebar-test'` only if the current admin page is `'widgets.php'`.

The right way is enqueue an external css, but for sake of semplicity I just echo the style.

This is the result:

[image: colored sidebar]

As you can see I styled the sidebar widget doind nothing else.

You can notice that the div with id equeal to sidebar id is *inside* the widget, if you want to style the widget *wrapper* or the title, only way is use javascript, something like:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  $('#sidebar-test').closest('.widgets-holder-wrap').addClass('sidebar-test-wrapper');
});
```

Using this code (that should be enqueued only in `widgets.php` page, you attach the class `'sidebar-test-wrapper'` to the container of your target sidebar, so you can style it.

If you want to style the name of the sidebar, you can use the class `'sidebar-name'`, in this case:

```
.sidebar-test-wrapper div.sidebar-name { /* some css here */ }
.sidebar-test-wrapper div.sidebar-name h3 { /* some css here */ }
.sidebar-test-wrapper div.sidebar-name .sidebar-name-arrow { /* some css here */ }
```

Comment: A very [classy classic related post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/limit-number-of-widgets-in-sidebars/23365#23365).

Comment: Is it possible to cahnge the header color too?

Comment: @Derfder yes, you need javascript. It's explained in the last part of the answer.

Comment: Javascript in regiser_sidebar() function? how to do that? I need that using only register_sidebar funcion no additional code.

Comment: @Derfder have you red the answer? _"code... that should be enqueued only in widgets.php page"_ so the javascript should go in a separate js file and enqueued in widgets.php page. If want to style the sidebar header only using something on register_sidebar, simply is not possible.

Comment: I need a solution in one function register_sidebar() !!! VERY IMPORTANT!!!

Comment: @Derfder using `register_sidebar` you can style only the div **inside** the widget. The widget header **can not** be changed using that function. I understand is important for you, but being important for you **doesn't** make it possible. So if you can't use code outside `register_sidebar` you can only style the part **inside** the widget.

Comment: @G.M. Sorry, but I will not choose you answer as the right one, because it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Derfder Don't worry, you are not required to accept any answer. However, this is **only my opinion**, when you ask for something and what you ask is not possible (simply ask for something don't make it possible) and someone answer you "sorry friend, what you ask is not possible" then that's the correct answer: an answer is not the right one when solve a problem, but when give the correct answer. E.g. if you ask "How can I fly using my arms?" and someone answer you "you can't because you are not a bird", that's the right answer.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks, I was thinking that it will make you upset. But now I am feeling better if you said that I shouldn't worry. I appreciate it very much.